# Backspace character not working when printing to a file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, command-line

I have simple C program-

```
main()
{
    printf("Foo\b");

}
```

It prints `Fo` on the terminal (as expected).

But when I call this program by redirecting the I/O-

```
./a.out >outfile
```

The `outfile` has `Foo` written in it.

Why is it so? and How can I print backspace character to standard output when it is set to a file.

---

**UPDATE:** Please note - `Foo` is followed by a space in the outfile. Why is that?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're opening the file with an editor and don't understand that the editor isn't a terminal and that the control character is non-printable?

Comment: If you look at the output of `stty -a`, you are likely to find that one of the options set is `echoe` which erases the previous character when an 'erase' (usually 'backspace') character is output.  That would account for the `Fo` output you see.

Comment: "Foo is followed by a space in the outfile" -- No it isn't.

Comment: How do you determine that `outfile` has `Foo` in it (which is actually correct; it should contain `Foo` followed by a backspace (not a space); the program printed a backspace, so the output contains a backspace).  One possible tool is `od -c outfile`, which should show that the file contains 4 characters, `F`, `o`, `o`, and `'\b`.  What happens when you type at the terminal is unrelated to the output you get when you cat a file to the terminal.

Comment: @JimBalter If it is not space then what follows `Foo`? All I can see is a blank character (space ofcourse)...

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya "what follows Foo" -- a backspace, as you would know if you actually paid attention to the responses you're getting. "All I can see" -- that has nothing to do with what's in the file. Let's put it this way: if there really is a backspace in the file, what would you **expect** to see after "Foo"? Hint: Backspace has no associated glyph, so something must be substituted.

Comment: `Foo is followed by a space in the outfile.` not space, ^H (\x08)

Answer (score 4):

Computers tend to represent text using distinct numbers for each character - for example, using the ASCII convention in which the character with numeric value 8 is a backspace, upper case letters start from 65, lower case from 97 etc....  So, your program is generating four characters of output: F, o, o and backspace - on screen you only see F and o because your terminal program interprets the backspace as a command to back up the cursor and remove the last-written character.  If you inspect outfile using another program, you may still see the second o and backspace: for example on Linux you could `cat -vt outfile`.

Files don't have that concept of interpreting backspaces as commands to remove earlier text, though if the file's concatenated to a terminal later it should operate exactly the same as when the program is run without redirection to a file.

Anyway, if you want to back up you'll need to use a file command to seek back one character then truncate or overwrite from there.  It can't be done through shell redirection - you need to open and control the file from within your program.

Comment: Ditto. Open your file with a hex editor and you'll see everything non-printable as well as printable.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya - instead of thinking of a file as a sequence of characters with special meanings, perhaps you could think of a file as a sequence of bytes. Each byte is just a number. Every number must be possible or else some files would not be possible. The special meanings happen when something interprets those bytes, but a file is just the sequence of bytes itself - it doesn't interpret.

Comment: @Steve314 Interestingly, `Foo `  is followed by a space in the outfile. Why is `\b` being interpreted it as space?

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya - Depending on how you display the file you might see something different. There's no standard visible representation of a backspace character - when it's displayed, whatever does the displaying has to invent a way.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya "Foo is followed by a space in the outfile." -- No it isn't. "Why is \b being interpreted it as space?" -- Because you're viewing the file with some program that displays non-glyphs as spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you `cat outfile` you will see the same result, because the file has the backspace control character in it and will behave as you expect on the terminal.  As Brian mentioned in comments, a text editor may or may not do something intelligent with the escape character.

Comment: You didn't answer the second part of my question...

Comment: Yes I did.  Cat it.  It will then go to stdout. The "space" you see in the editor is the backspace character.